# Perl LWP::Simple won't "get" a webpage when running from remote server

Tags: perl, lwp

I'm trying to use Perl to scrape a publications list as follows:

```
use XML::XPath;
use XML::XPath::XMLParser;
use LWP::Simple;

my $url = "https://connects.catalyst.harvard.edu/Profiles/profile/xxxxxxx/xxxxxx.rdf";

my $content = get($url);
die "Couldn't get publications!" unless defined $content;
```

When I run it on my local (Windows 7) machine it works fine.  When I try to run it on the linux server where we are hosting some websites, it dies.  I installed XML and LWP using cpan so those should be there.  I'm wondering if the problem could be some sort of security or permissions on the server (keeping it from accessing an external website), but I don't even know where to start with that.  Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried seeing what `$!` says?

Comment: $! says "No such file or directory" so it's probably being blocked from accessing external URLs.  Now I need to figure out how to unblock it.

Comment: `$!` is only meaningful after making a system call that returned false. You didn't make a system call. Again, you'll need to use LWP::UserAgent to see the error message.

Comment: Likely possibilities (in no particular order): *) Blocked by firewall. *) Certificate issue. *) Proxy needed. *) SELinux or other hardening system preventing outgoing connections.

Comment: I used LWP::UserAgent as suggested and it turns out I didn't have " LWP::Protocol::https" installed.  Whoops.  Installing that fixed the problem. Thanks everyone (especially those who suggested UserAgent).  Glad it wasn't more complicated.

Comment: @Compysaurus Great! Please write an answer so it's easier for future visitors to see what you did.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out I didn't have LWP::Protocol::https" installed.  I found this out by switching

```
LWP::Simple
```

to

```
LWP::UserAgent
```

and adding the following:

```
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
my $resp = $ua->get('https://connects.catalyst.harvard.edu/Profiles/profile/xxxxxx/xxxxxxx.rdf' );
print $resp;
```

It then returned an error telling me it didn't have the protocol to access the https without LWP::Protocol::https, so I installed it with

```
cpan LWP::Protocol::https
```

and all was good.